# Webview in scrollviewer windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, webview

I have a scrollviewer which has a gridview as content.
In the datatemplate of the grid view, there is a 2 column grid.
In the first column there is a flipview and in the second a webview.
One gridviewitem take all the screen. When I scroll, the webview make an effect. It's like the webview is not fixed and does not scroll at the same time as the other elements.

Do you know why? Can I remove this effect?

Thank you

(I develop in C#/XAML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebView can be difficult to work.  To solve your problem, take a look at the [WebViewBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush) to render the content of your WebView onto a Rectangle that will behave better.  Use WebViewBrush when scrolling and also to prevent the WebView from remaining in the foreground when it is supposed to be covered by an overlay but the WebView remains at the highest position in the z-order.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I've already tried to use the WebViewBrush, but the problem is that the Content is too long, and as we can't scroll in a rectangle, this solution can't work for me...

Comment: The strategy is to disable the webview when scrolling the scrollviewer or showing overlays, and then enable the webview when scrolling stops or the overlay is no longer overlapping